# Void return in an API request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

The client and a generic method for the API requests are created here:

```
public class Client : IDisposable
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    private void CreateClient()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient(); 
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("KEY", token);
    }


    public void Dispose() => _client?.Dispose();

    public enum Method { GET, POST, PUT, DELETE }

    public HttpResponseMessage Request(string url, Method method, object data, HttpContent request)
    {
        if (data != null)
            request = new StringContent(Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        switch (method)
        {
            case Method.POST: return _client.PostAsync(url, request).Result;
            case Method.PUT: return _client.PutAsync(url, request).Result;
            case Method.DELETE: return _client.DeleteAsync(url).Result;
            default: return _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        }
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> RequestAsync(string url, Method method, object data, HttpContent request)
    {
        if (data != null)
            request = new StringContent(Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        switch (method)
        {
            case Method.GET: return _client.GetAsync(url);
            case Method.POST: return _client.PostAsync(url, request);
            case Method.PUT: return _client.PutAsync(url, request);
            case Method.DELETE: return _client.DeleteAsync(url);
            default: return _client.GetAsync(url);
        }
    }

    public string Post(string url, object data) =>
        Request(url, Method.POST, data, null).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, object data) =>
        RequestAsync(url, Method.POST, data, null);

    //UTILS

    private static string Serialize(object data) =>
        data == null
            ? string.Empty
            : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
}
```

I'm trying to call these methods to specific classes, to simplify the usage of it for the customer. For example, to create a new checkout for a transaction in a credit card:

```
public class Checkout : SDK
{
    private static Client client;

    public Checkout() => client = new Client();

    public static async Task Credit(object data) => 
        await client.PostAsync(url, data);
}
```

The request needs to be mounted based on a few models, that can have this structure and I'm trying to generate it in a simple way, like this:

```
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction
        {
            PaymentMethod = new PaymentMethod { Code = "1" },
            Application = "Test",
            Vendor = "Name",
            Customer = new Customer
            {
                //Customer details...
            },
            Products = new List<TransactionProduct>
            {
                //Products...
            }
        };

        var teste = Checkout.Credit(transaction);
        Console.WriteLine(teste);
    }
```

And all I get as return is:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]
Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

I've tried to add `await` for the `Checkout.Credit` call, but I get:

```
CS0815  Test C# Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable
```

Unit testing this with a simple HttpClient requests works like a charm, but I'm not being able to identify the problem on my project structure, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Task` is the return type for an `async` method *that does not have a return value*.

Or, to put it another way, `async` wraps `T` values into `Task<T>` (or `void` returns into `Task`), and `await` unwraps those values. Since `Credit` returns `Task`, the type of the expression `Checkout.Credit(transaction)` is `Task`, and the type of the expression `await Checkout.Credit(transaction)` is `void`. And you cannot assign `void` to `var teste`; that's what the compiler error is saying.

To fix this, give your `async` method return types. In particular:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Credit(object data) => 
    await client.PostAsync(url, data);
```

On a side note, this is quite strange:

```
public string Post(string url, object data) => ...;
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, object data) => ...;
```

Usually, if you have a `Method` and a `MethodAsync` where `Method` has some return type `TResult`, then `MethodAsync` will have the return type `Task<TResult>`, not `Task<SomeCompletelyDifferentType>`. A more natural API would be something like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, object data)
{
  var result = await Request(url, Method.POST, data, null);
  return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: And this is why I direct people to your posts on tasks...well done sir